# swift using filter to get the difference between two arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have an array of the following:

```
var cardsInHand = [1,2,3]
```

I want to be able to have two arrays of `cardsInHand` and `cardsOnTable`.  `cardsOnTable` can only be from `cardsInHand`. For example, if I play card 1, then `cardsInHand` will be `[2,3]` and cardsOnTable will be `[1]`.  I can accomplish this using filter, but the value removed from `cardsInHand` is lost.  The inverse is true, if I card 1 backup, then `cardsInHand` will be `[1,2,3]` and `cardsOnTable` will be `[]`

```
let cardsPlayed = 1

cardsInHand = cardsInHand.filter { $0 != cardsPlayed }

print(cardsInHand)

[2,3]
```

How can I get the `cardsOnTable` be the difference between `cardsPlayed` and `cardsInHand`?

Sorry if the heading is misleading, but I wasn't sure how to describe it.  I have a feeling that map, reduce or filter might be the easiest way to handle this.

Comment: Was that supposed to be `cardsInHand.filter { cardsPlayed.contains($0) }`?

Comment: Instead of filtering the cardsInHand you should only append to cardsPlayed the cards that are returned when removing it from cardsInHand

Comment: " but the value removed from cardsInHand is lost." --> what does it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `remove(at:)` func for achieving your goal, like this

```
let cardsPlayed = 1
    if let index = cardsInHand.index(of: cardsPlayed)
    {
        cardsOnTable += [cardsInHand.remove(at: index)]
    }
```

In the case there are multiple cards which are dropped, like you have mentioned in comment, you can directly store them into an array `cardsOntable` and use like this

```
        cardsOnTable += [1,2]
    cardsInHand = cardsInHand.filter{!self.cardsOnTable.contains($0)}
```

Comment: how would this work if let cardsPlayed = [1,2] as an array instead of an Int?  Your suggestion is great!

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please reply if it helps you or if you have any query. Thanks